# Letter "i" doesn't work in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have a problem with my htaccess, I have no idea why this not working.
I'm trying to :

path/path/1 and path/path/string

Everything works for the id (0-9) and for the string, while I'm not using the letter "i" its working. But with the letter "i" nothing works.

I have no idea why.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)/([0-9-_]+) index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)/([abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+) index.php?p=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
#work without letter i
```

then

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)/([0-9-_]+) index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)/([a-z]+) index.php?p=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
#not working
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `A-ZabcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz` I not i

Comment: The second one should match tho. what's the relation between the first and second set of rules? "then"?

Comment: can you include the exact example that's not matching, the path of the request you're expecting your rule to match

Comment: Here [ZabcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz0 ] you have included 'I' not 'i'. This might me the reason.

Comment: first htaccess without user letter i working, second using all leter a-z not working